# why i need to initialize this member array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

If I don't initialize this member array 'arryMem' with same expected length,I get nullPointerException but with initialization it works,Help to make me understand this plz.

```
class BubRec {

    Integer arryMem[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};// if arrMem[]; throws NullPointerException
    int n;


    BubRec(Integer ary[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= ary.length - 1; i++) {
            arryMem[i] = ary[i];
        }
        n = arryMem.length;
    }


    Integer[] sortBubRec() {
        int temp = 0;
        if (n >= 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (arryMem.length - 1); i++) {
                if (arryMem[i] > arryMem[i + 1]) {
                    temp = arryMem[i];
                    arryMem[i] = arryMem[i + 1];
                    arryMem[i + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
            n--;
            sortBubRec();
        }
        return arryMem;
    }
}

public class BubbleRecMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer arry[] = {34, 56, 78, 1, 2, 4, 7};
        BubRec bubRec = new BubRec(arry);
        Integer sortedArry[] = bubRec.sortBubRec();
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedArry.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(sortedArry[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 4 7 34 56 78
```

Comment: How would you expect to access an uninitialized array?

Comment: Its obvious you are trying to access the array element without even initializing it i.e at arryMem[i]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have to specify the length of the array before trying to populate it.

You can do that by using `arryMem = new Integer[ary.length];` in your BubRec constructor:

```
class BubRec {

    Integer arryMem[];
    int n;

    BubRec(Integer ary[]) {
        arryMem = new Integer[ary.length];
        for (int i = 0; i <= ary.length - 1; i++) {
            arryMem[i] = ary[i];
        }
        n = arryMem.length;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write `Integer arryMem [] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};`, java allocates an array of length *7*, because you inserted seven elements. Alternate you can allocate an array of the same length by typing `Integer arryMem [] = new Integer [7]`. If you insert the values directly, java do this automatically for you.

You problem now is that when you type `Integer arrayMem [];`, nobody allocates any memory nether java because, you didn't insert any values, nor you. So if you call an *element* in this array, you get a *NullPointerException*, because there aren't any elements...

So you **must** allocate memory (create the object), before you can use it. You can do it as already seen by multiple ways. You can do this and initialize all elements in one step by typing...

```
this.arryMem = Arrays.copyOf(ary, ary.length);
```

...in your constructor.

Comment: Good solution, but I think that the odds of somebody knowing about that solution and not knowing how to instantiate an array at the same time are pretty low